# C# Convert List<T> to Object Properties

Tags: c#, list, object, converters

I'm looking for a way to convert `List<Tag>` items to `Object` Properties.
For example, I want to convert each tag so that the value of tag's `name` is a new object property name and the value of tag's `value` is the object property's value.

e.g.
Convert `List`: `[{"name":"KS_1","value":123},{"name":"KS_2","value":"ABC"}]`
Into `Object`: `{KS_1: 123, KS_2: "ABC"}`

The object names and values are not predefined.
I'm using .Net 3.5 so I can't use `ExpandoObject`

Comment: You can do this with reflection, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Are the names known before run time?  If not, you could use an [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How would you access those properties? Either look at the `ExpandoObject` or you'll have to create types with the [TypeBuilder](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/dynamically-create-a-class-at-runtime/)

Comment: The names and values are not predefined.

Comment: WHY down vote? if you have a solution please share it.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I'm using .NET 3.5 so no `ExpandoObject`

Comment: Try the Typebuilder: Here is an example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/dynamically-create-a-class-at-runtime/

Comment: So you don't even have a class to put the values into? What exactly do you want to do with this object once you've created it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved by using an anonymous type using Linq as follows.

```
var Result = new Object()
{
    KS_1: List[0].value,
    KS_2: List[1].value
};
```

However, if a variable list of list members is required, reflection must be used.

Comment: The names are not predefined.

Comment: If the names are not known at compile time, how are the values to be accessed; via reflection?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use reflection. Here's an extension method that does the job:

```
public T FromTags<T>(this List<Tag> tags)
    where T : new()
{
    var t = new T();

    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    foreach (var tag in tags)
    {
        var property = properties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == tag.name);

        if (property != null)
        {
            property.SetValue(t, tag.value);
        }
    }

    return t;
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
public class MyThing
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}

var myThing = tags.FromTags<MyThing>();
```